# Display number input on the screen in pygame

Tags: python, string, numbers, pygame

I have got this code:

```
def get_key():
  while 1:
    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
      return event.key
    else:
      pass

def display_box(screen, message):
  fontobject = pygame.font.Font(None,40)
  if len(message) != 0:
    screen.blit(fontobject.render(message, 1, (0,255,0)),((screen.get_width() / 2) - 300, (screen.get_height() / 2)-50 ))
  pygame.display.flip()

def ask(screen, question):
  current_string = []
  display_box(screen, question + ": " + string.join(current_string,""))
  while 1:
    inkey = get_key()
    if inkey == K_BACKSPACE:
      current_string = current_string[0:-1]
    elif inkey == K_RETURN:
      break
    elif inkey == K_MINUS:
      current_string.append("_")
    elif inkey <= 127:
      current_string.append(chr(inkey))
    display_box(screen, question + ": " + string.join(current_string,""))
  return int(string.join(current_string,""))
```

This code is supposed to display what the user has inputed on the keyboard onto the screen. Although it works with letters, the backspace does not work with numbers. I think it has something to do with

```
string.join(current_string,"")
```

in

```
def ask(screen, question)
```

, but I do not know how to fix this.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you actually clean up the screen. There should be some form of fill() command to set the screen to a background color before blitting the newest message to it. Otherwise, you're blitting a message with one fewer character to the screen exactly on top of the last message.